# XML-RPC with angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular, xml-rpc

How to make XML-RPC with angular 2 typescript?

Comment: google `XML-RPC js`, and use that. :)

Comment: not maintained and not TS

Comment: You can use the typings to get code hinting: `npm install @types/xmlrpc --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Is just falow the official instructions on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlrpc

the only change is:
when:

```
var xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc');
```

use:

```
import xmlrpc  = require("xmlrpc");
```

after that you just continue like the javascript code.

> **Spoiler Alert!** If you are calling by application web (angular-cli) your requests will be turn in a ["preflighted request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)